# Unity rotation between two 3d objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I need to sync transform between Head and Body objects (both of them are 3d objects) in Unity and need to satisfy flowing conditions:

- Translation must be same between Head and Body, likes Fixed Join.
- Rotation must be free in x and z axis and
- rotation in y axis between them less than or equal 30 degree. It means that if Body has Y-angle of 0 and Head has Y-angle of 31 then Y-angle of Body will be rotate to 1 degree, position must not change.

[image]

I am new in Unity. I spent 2 days to read about Hinge Joint, Character Joint and Configurable Joint but not lucky. Many thanks for any helps, both of config in Unity Editor or C# scripts are also welcome!

Comment: "Unfortunately" StackOverflow is not supposed to be a "Please code that for me" page but a community for getting help with specific coding problems. All you request can be done by some simple `transform.position = ...` and `transform.rotation = ..` and `Mathf.Clamp` calls. .. so please do some more reserach and come back with a specific coding related issue and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code

Comment: Why don't you put head and body into an empty parent GameObject, this would make things much simpler for you.

Comment: @PierreBaret thank you for suggest, I tried but I don't know how to deal with 30 degree problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont say i never gave you nothing.... :

```
// gobal 
 private float rotationY = 0f;
 private float sensitivityY = 2f;

 void lockedRotation()
 {
    rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityY;
    rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationZ, -15, 15);

     transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.localEulerAngles.x, -rotationY,transform.localEulerAngles.z);
 }
```

now i have set you in the right direction. play with this and see what you can make. we cant do all the work for you. good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I will do some searching to understand your code, when it work I will mark your answer!